# Como hacer para mostrar los datos del json

Tags: javascript

que tal, estoy haciendo una pequeña practica con .NetCore, mi duda es la siguiente. ¿Como puedo hacer para que que se recargue una seccion donde muestro el resultado de json?

```
function Get_Product(idC)
{
    if(idC == undefined)
{
    print_products(url_Product);
}
else
{
    let url = url_Product + "/" + idC;

    print_products(url);
}
}

function print_products(link)
{
fetch(link).then(function(Data){
    return Data.json();
}).then(function(Data){
    for( i = 0; i < Data.length; i++)
    {
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("card");
        let p = document.createElement("p");


        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = Data[i].url_image;

        p.innerHTML = Data[i].name;


        div.appendChild(img);
        div.appendChild(p);
        document.getElementById("content").appendChild(div);
    }
    
})

}
```

Estoy mandando un parametro para una consulta sql en una api, pero cuando elijo una opción no logro hacer que me muestre el nuevo json creado.

Comment: Y si le haces un console.log(Data) que te aparece?

Comment: Me aparece el array del json creado de la consulta a la BD. Solo me falta quitar el json anterior para mostrar el nuevo